# Mysql before insert trigger to check whether all values are present in the sql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table abc of the below format

```
create table abc(id int, name varchar(20));
insert into abc values(1, "Tom");
```

Now I m adding a new column `price`

```
`alter table abc add column price varchar(20) after id;`
```

I need a before insert trigger which will set the value of price to '' if its not provided in the insert statement. That is it should work with the existing insert statement `insert into abc values(1, "Tom");`

I have written a trigger but it is throwing error saying count of the column doesnt match when i try to run the insert statement

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggerForAbc;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER triggerForAbc BEFORE insert ON `abc`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (NEW.price IS NULL OR NEW.price = '') THEN
            SET NEW.price = '';
      ELSE
            SET NEW.price = NEW.price;
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ??? Trigger not needed. Simply alter this column definition and add `DEFAULT ''` option. If the value for this column is not provided in the query then default value will be assigned into.

Comment: But then the existing queries will still fail right? I cant modify the existing queries

Comment: Nope, the default value will take care of the existing queries. However, having price as varchar is a strange choice as price is a number.

Comment: *But then the existing queries will still fail right?* Depends on the query. If it is accurate and specifies the columns to be assigned into (`INSERT INTO abc (id, name) VALUES ..`) then setting the default value will solve, and the query will work. If the query is inaccurate and does not specify the columns list (`INSERT INTO abc VALUES ..`) then nothing can help - you'll always receive "Error 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" And nothing can solve - the columns count is checked before any trigger firing. https://dbfiddle.uk/kLcwCefd

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But my original question was whether there is any way we could alter the insert query to make it something like this ```insert into abc ( 2, '', "Matt")``` or ```insert into abc(id, name) values( 2, "Matt")``` So that I dont wanna make changes to existing queries and minimise the change by adding this trigger or any other methods

Comment: Validation occurs before the trigger fires so you have to specify columns to be inserted or set a default in the table schema.

Comment: Keep `price` as the last column, with a default as mentioned previously, then existing queries will not need to be modified, only new queries that will insert a price when needed. I also agree that a trigger seems to be overkill for this need.